# Convert int64_t to double

Tags: c++, type-conversion

```
  int64_t a = 1234;

  double d = (double) a;
```

Is this the recommended way?

Comment: int64 does not always map well to double. for example compare the maximum value of a double and the maximum value of int64. also note that double has 57 bits of integers, higher than that you are skipping some integers that cannot be represented in double format.  while int64 has 64 bits of integers, all adjacent to their neighbor by 1. they are very different ranges of numbers.

Answer (score 18):

use `static_cast` as strager answers.  I recommend *against* using the implicit cast (or even a C-style cast in C++ source code) for a few reasons:

- Implicit casts are a common source of compiler warnings, meaning you may be adding noise to the build (either now, or later when better warning flags are added).
- The next maintenance programmer behind you will see an implicit cast, and needs to know if it was intentional behavior or a mistake/bug.  Having that `static_cast` makes your *intent* immediately obvious.
- `static_cast` and the other C++-style casts are easy for `grep` to handle.

Comment: On "intent": especially when the assignment is far from the declaration of d, static_cast<double> violates DRY. d = static_cast<typeof(d)>(a) is better in that respect, but then I lose the will to live and figure maybe d = a would be better after all ;-)

Comment: You're right that it violates DRY... but C++ as a language isn't DRY anyhow, if you consider forward declarations.  Also, IIRC, typeof(d) requires RTTI and <typeinfo>, which isn't usable in some environments.

Comment: ...though you're right... the DRY violation would cause some weird code if someone does an incomplete refactoring.  float d; d = static_cast<double>(value); // WTF

Answer (score 9):

You should use `static_cast` or rely on the implicit cast instead:

```
int64_t a = 1234;
double d = static_cast<double>(a);
double f = a;
```

Answer (score 5):

You can also use the conversion syntax, which is equivalent to a static_cast:

```
int64_t a = 1234;
double d = double(a);
```

This is a useful syntactic construction in that it allows primitive and class types to be treated the same way in template code, either doing a static_cast, for the primitive, or invoking a constructor, for the class type.

Answer (score 4):

For POD types both versions do the same thing. Choose the one you prefer and be consistent.

I know many people who prefer the former for typing/readability and I tend to agree with this but I can live with either.

I've heard the "easy to grep for" argument many times but have yet to ever come across a situation where I've needed to grep my codebase for POD casts.