# How can I store the bits of a uint64_t inside of a double?

Tags: c, r

Basically I have a `uint64_t` whose actual value I do not care about.  I need to store it in a `double` so that I can easily store the bits in an object in R (if you don't know what that is, that's fine, it doesn't matter for the question).

So what I would like is a means of storing the 64 bits of the `uint64_t` inside of a `double` and then also convert from the `double` holding the bits back to the original `uint64_t`.

I've been banging my head against the wall on this for a quite a bit (is that a pun?) so any and all help is greatly appreciated!!!

Comment: Such a conversion is violating the strict aliasing rule in C and considered to invoke an undefined behavior. But generally you can just `memcpy` from the address of first variable, to the second one...

Comment: Did you see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/691935/convert-int64-t-to-double) SO post?  By the way, nice pun :-)

Comment: So the key here for me is that I don't want to use the `double` as anything other than a means of storing the bits of the original `uint64_t`.  This is because in R I don't have access to `uint64_t` types in the way I need so I just want to store those 64 bits in the `double` and use them in C code.  I'll look into `memcpy`.  If you're confident in that please post as an answer so I can accept it @EugeneSh !

Comment: What about https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/bit64/bit64.pdf ? Also https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-packages/2012/001287.html

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux I don't want to use the value in R actually at any time.  Solely need to deal with it on the C side and just have it stored in R.  It may be useful to go through their source code though.  Thanks for the tip!

Comment: I understand you need it for storage, but even printing to check if you got right value is a LOT easier with bit64 than with int-as-double

Comment: It's a lot easier if you can relax the requirement to "one uint64 to two doubles"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the comments, you can use [memcpy](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/memcpy.3.html) to copy the bits from your `uint64_t` to a `double`.

This works because the size of a `double` is the same as the one of an `uint64_t` (8 bytes).

If you try to display the values, you won't get the same result, though. Indeed a double stores both positive and negative values, with a floating point, whereas an `uint64_t` is... unsigned and whole.

The *binary representation* is the same, the *interpreted value* is different.

Comment: Cheater ;). Can't choose this!

Comment: Double is usually 8 on a modern architecture, but C allows it to be any size.

Comment: @EugeneSh. It works.  What's wrong with it?  Reinterpreting the pointer shouldn't change the actual bits in any way.  It's much lower overhead than actually copying memory.  Seems to be a really good strategy actually...

Comment: @iShouldUseAName If we are speaking of the other (accepted) answer, according to C standard it is invoking undefined behavior. Which is worse than just "not working", as sometimes it seems to work. This specific UB is *rarely* not working. But still.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I see.  If you can show me a scenario where it doesn't work, I'm more than happy to change it.

Comment: @iShouldUseAName It is **undefined**. It means there is *no* scenario where it is definitely works or not.

Comment: @EugeneSh. That's not really what undefined means, but I get your general point.  I've switched chosen answers to reflect that.

Comment: This blog post dives into a few cases where this undefined behavior can poke its ugly head: http://blog.qt.io/blog/2011/06/10/type-punning-and-strict-aliasing/.

Answer (score -2):

in C casting is your friend:

- dbl = * (double*)(&ui64);
- ui64 = * (uint64_t*)(&dbl);

example:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdio.h>

double dbl_1 = 42.42;
uint64_t ui64_1;

double dbl_2;
uint64_t ui64_2 = 0x404535C28F5C28F6;

void main(void)
{
   ui64_1 = *(uint64_t*)(&dbl_1);
   printf("%" PRIx64 "\n", ui64_1);

   dbl_2 = *(double*)(&ui64_2);
   printf("%f", dbl_2); 
}
```

Great resource for conversions:
[IEEE-754 Floating-Point Conversion](http://babbage.cs.qc.cuny.edu/IEEE-754.old/Decimal.html)

Edit: This is undefined behavior per the C standards and although it may work, it is not best practice.

Comment: I independently got to doing this so I'll choose it as the answer.

Comment: This is undefined behavior because the types aren't compatible. The correct solution is to use memcpy.

Comment: Yes this is undefined behavior and I have updated the answer to state this. I agree as well that the other answer should be the correct / excepted answer.

Comment: @user1373984 Relying on undefined behavior is not just a bad practice. It is a plainly wrong thing.